# Swift: WKWebView reduce content resolution, scall to fill

Tags: swift, webview

In my webview I want to display the content with a smaller resolution so that all the content is bigger and more readable. The text, photo, ...

So that all the content is bigger. I also want to stretch the height so that it takes the whole screen.

By what way can I do that?

How can I set the resolution of the webview?

[image]

My code:

```
extension PatientReportsViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate {

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

    }

    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    }

    private func loadUrlIntoWebView(url: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }

        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }

    func setupWebView(type: String, baseURL: String, path: String) {
        guard let scriptString = viewModel.getAndroidJSCode(type: type, baseURL: baseURL) else { return }

        let contentController = WKUserContentController()
        contentController.add(self, name: "android")

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = contentController

        let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptString, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)
        config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)

        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        containerWebView.addSubview(webView)
        webView.fillSuperView(padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: -8, left: -8, bottom: 0, right: -8))
        webView.contentMode = .scaleToFill // Not working

        loadUrlIntoWebView(url: baseURL + path)
    }

}
```